# Creating a python file with python

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

my goal to is to Create a python file with a python-script itself containing the following code. Although the variables E1, E2... should be exchanged by the value itself.

```
rho_hom=1
E1=11
E2=22
E3=33
v12=.12
v13=.13
v23=.23
G12=12
G13=13
G23=23

ModelName = 'Model-1' 
mdb.models[ModelName].Material(name='Mat-hom'))
mdb.models[ModelName].materials['Mat-hom'].Density(table=((rho_hom, ), )))
mdb.models[ModelName].materials['Mat-hom'].Elastic(type=ENGINEERING_CONSTANTS, table=((E1, E2, E3, v12, v13, v23, G12, G13, G23), ))
```

I've tried out a couple things, but i can't figure out how to code this since the problem are the '-sign in the code. How do I implement a ' into a file. I'm thankful for any advice!

```
file = open("newfile.py", "w")
file.write(
ModelName = 'Model-1' 
mdb.models[ModelName].Material(name='Mat-hom'))
mdb.models[ModelName].materials['Mat-hom'].Density(table=((rho_hom, ), )))
mdb.models[ModelName].materials['Mat-hom'].Elastic(type=ENGINEERING_CONSTANTS, table=((E1, E2, E3, v12, v13, v23, G12, G13, G23), ))

)

file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there, you would like to pass `"""` into your file writer:

```
file = open("newfile.py", "w")
file.write("""
ModelName = 'Model-1' 
mdb.models[ModelName].Material(name='Mat-hom'))
mdb.models[ModelName].materials['Mat-hom'].Density(table=((rho_hom, ), )))
mdb.models[ModelName].materials['Mat-hom'].Elastic(type=ENGINEERING_CONSTANTS, table=((E1, E2, E3, v12, v13, v23, G12, G13, G23), ))

""")

file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't aware there were these " and these ' to solve this problem. I haven't tested your code, but mine works now fine.